# What is the remainder if you divide $2^{804}$ by 257

Tags: number-theory

What is the remainder if you divide $2^{804}$ by 257.  I got an answer 16.  Would that be right? 
I split the denominator 257 to be $(2^8+1)$.  I split the numerator $2^{12}$ times $(2^{8})^{99}+4096-4096$, which again can be split as (assuming $2^8$ to be x) ($x^{99}+1$) 4096 times and each divisible by 257 ($2^8+1$). Then I divide 4096/257 = 257*15 +241.  And finally subtract (257-241) = 16.  Let me know if this is correct.

Comment: How did you get $16$ as a result? Can you explain your method?

Comment: Yes, the answer and reasoning are both correct, though it could use a little more explanation of how you know that $x^{99}+1$ is a multiple of $257$.

Comment: when n is odd $(x^n+1)$ is divisible by x+1..  That was the reasoning that went behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $257$ is a prime number and Fermat's little theorem tells us that,

$$2^{256}\equiv 1\pmod{257}$$

Hence, we have,

$$2^{804}\equiv 2^{804~\bmod~256}\equiv 2^{36}\equiv (256)^4\times 16\equiv (-1)^4\times 16\equiv 16\pmod{257}$$

Comment: Or, you can avoid FLT just by doing it like this: $$2^{804}\equiv (256)^{100}\times 2^4\equiv (-1)^{100}\times 16\equiv 16\pmod{257}$$

Answer (score 3):

$2^{804}=2^4(2^8)^{100}=16\cdot(257-1)^{100}=16+(\text{multiples of 257})$.

The remainder is then evidently 16.

Answer (score 2):

257 is the 3rd (prime) Fermat number, hence $$2^{2^3}=2^8\equiv -1\mod 257.$$
So $2^{804}\equiv (-1)^{100}\cdot2^4= 16\mod 257$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$2^8=256\equiv-1\pmod{257}$$ so $$2^{16} \equiv 1 \pmod{257}$$